My Cosmos DB Emulator with Java and Spring Boot connection keeps timing out
I am following this guide here from Microsoft to set up the Cosmos DB emulator using NoSQL api with docker on a Windows 11 machine.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-develop-emulator?tabs=docker-linux%2Ccsharp&pivots=api-nosql
I have downloaded all the required software, and I have successfully set up a running image of Cosmos-DB emulator with docker.

Now, I am on Intellij, and I am able to successfully start up my Java and Spring Boot project to connect with the local Azure Cosmos DB Emulator. The library I am using to connect with the emulator is the following
implementation 'com.azure:azure-spring-data-cosmos:5.17.1'

I am using this library as I am using Java with Spring Boot and I am able to connect and run against an actual Azure Cosmos DB account on my Azure portal.
Locally though, it is complaining about socket timeout with the following error message:
2024-10-11T16:30:32.352-04:00  WARN 23028 --- [tor-http-nio-17] c.a.c.implementation.ClientRetryPolicy   : marking the endpoint https://172.17.0.2:8081/ as unavailable for read
2024-10-11T16:30:32.352-04:00  INFO 23028 --- [tor-http-nio-17] c.a.c.i.RxDocumentClientImpl             : Getting database account endpoint from https://localhost:8081
2024-10-11T16:30:54.432-04:00  WARN 23028 --- [tor-http-nio-18] c.a.c.i.d.GatewayAddressCache            : Network failure

io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection timed out: getsockopt: /172.17.0.2:8081
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: getsockopt
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:682) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:973) ~[na:na]
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:336) ~[netty-transport-4.1.110.Final.jar:4.1.110.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:339) ~[netty-transport-4.1.110.Final.jar:4.1.110.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:776) ~[netty-transport-4.1.110.Final.jar:4.1.110.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724) ~[netty-transport-4.1.110.Final.jar:4.1.110.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[netty-transport-4.1.110.Final.jar:4.1.110.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562) ~[netty-transport-4.1.110.Final.jar:4.1.110.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:994) ~[netty-common-4.1.110.Final.jar:4.1.110.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.110.Final.jar:4.1.110.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.110.Final.jar:4.1.110.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[na:na]

This is how my I set up the extended AbstractCosmosConfiguration class
@Bean
    public CosmosClientBuilder getCosmosClientBuilder() {
        final DirectConnectionConfig directConnectionConfig = new DirectConnectionConfig();
        final GatewayConnectionConfig gatewayConnectionConfig = new GatewayConnectionConfig();
        return new CosmosClientBuilder()
                .endpoint("https://localhost:8081")
                .credential(new ManagedIdentityCredentialBuilder()
                        .build())
                .key("my primary key")
                .directMode(directConnectionConfig, gatewayConnectionConfig)
                .clientTelemetryConfig(
                        new CosmosClientTelemetryConfig()
                                .diagnosticsThresholds(
                                        new CosmosDiagnosticsThresholds()
                                )
                                .diagnosticsHandler(CosmosDiagnosticsHandler.DEFAULT_LOGGING_HANDLER));
    }

    @Override
    public CosmosConfig cosmosConfig() {
        return CosmosConfig.builder()
                .enableQueryMetrics(cosmosProperties.isQueryMetricsEnabled())
                .enableIndexMetrics(cosmosProperties.isIndexMetricsEnabled())
                .responseDiagnosticsProcessor(new ResponseDiagnosticsProcessorImplementation())
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return "Database Name";
    }

    private static class ResponseDiagnosticsProcessorImplementation implements ResponseDiagnosticsProcessor {

        @Override
        public void processResponseDiagnostics(@Nullable final ResponseDiagnostics responseDiagnostics) {
            log.info("Response Diagnostics {}", responseDiagnostics);
        }
    }

What am I missing to fix this issue?

Looks like a Network failure?

Your CosmosClientBuilder() seems to have some issues (like, you should not be using a managed identity for the emulator, and you shouldn't have to worry about direct or gateway configs). Probably shouldn't even worry about telemetry - none of that should be needed (especially when trying to diagnose). Just be sure to set key to the built-in emulator key.

@DavidMakogon How should I use a managed identity for the emulator? The telemetry and direct or gateway configs was set up with the Cosmos DB on Azure portal, I can remove them. I believe the key I set (copied from the localhost emulator) should be correct as any alteration of the key prevents the app from even starting up.

For anyone else also getting socket time out, I believe this is because of what @KeithJackson mentioned as per his post here:
Cosmos DB Docker Container Just Hangs when CosmosClient methods are called
I deleted my old Docker image that I got from Microsoft's example and used the docker command he wrote up and so far, I am no longer seeing a socket time out issue.

   try {
                let intent = new android.content.Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                // let context = application.android.currentContext;
                let context = application.android.context;
                let mimeType = this.findExtension(extension);
                /*
                mimeType = mimeType.getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension.replace(".", 
                "").toLowerCase());
               */
                /** Grant permission for third party apps to read the content of this file */
                intent.addFlags(android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.addFlags(android.content.Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                
                let chooserIntent = android.content.Intent.createChooser(intent, title);
                chooserIntent.addFlags(android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
          chooserIntent.addFlags(android.content.Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                /** Set the file content URI using Android native APIs */
                intent.setDataAndType(androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".fileprovider", new java.io.File(file.path)), mimeType);
                context.startActivity(chooserIntent);
            } catch (e) {
                console.log("ERROR: Cannot open file " + e);
                return false;
            }


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?

I don't understand how this answer is related to the question, as the question literally has nothing to do with Android, and your answer has nothing to do with Cosmos DB.

@JeremyCaney - it's not a correct answer (even if it had explanatory details). Well, it may be a correct answer for a completely different question, but it's not related in any way whatsoever to the question. It's not clear why it was posted here.
